# Hp proBook 4540s windows 7 64 bit

Tags: laptop, bios, hp-pavilion

I have an HP [ProBook 4540s](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03349886). I recently updated the BIOS from the HP website. After a few days of normally working on my laptop, I tried to switch it on and the screen is black with a continuously blinking Caps Lock light. I tried to recover the BIOS through the combination key and the flash memory, but it doesn't respond. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: There is a problem with your power adapter. See https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/65553iC29A4E094BCBF83B/

Comment: The contious blinking led is the caps lock led not the power.

Comment: Does it actually blink continuously or is there a pause in between? @DavidPostill's link shows some Caps Lock blink codes.

Comment: Caps lock light blinking like one blink per second continiously.

Comment: David postill's link didn't show caps lock light blinking 1 blink/second continously.

Comment: Can you attach an external monitor to see if there's any image on it?

Comment: I attached it to a monitor but nothing changed and both the laptop screen and the monitor is black and the caps lock light is blinking continously.